# Cannot detect element by classname

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner and I am using pure javascript for DOM manipulation. I am not able to get all the divs in my section element. I get undefined. Please tell me what is the error and how I can fix it.

**HTML**

```
    <section class="main-content">
        <aside>
            <p>
                <span class="sidebartext">Watch this space for breaking news items.</span>
            </p>
        </aside>

        <section class="notes">
            <div id="Services" class="nav-pages active">Services</div>
            <div id="Resources" class="nav-pages">Resources</div>
            <div id="Contact-Us" class="nav-pages">Contact Us</div>
            <div id="Company" class="nav-pages">Company</div>
        </section>

    </section>
```

**JS**

```
var navTabs = document.getElementsByClassName('notes').children;
console.log(navTabs);//undefined
```

**No jQuery answers please !!!**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an *array* of elements (actually, array-like - see @Hamms comment below), so `children` is undefined on it. If there's only one notes section, you can choose to use `id="notes"` instead (with `getElementById`) or iterate through the above array and access children from that.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` actually returns [an HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), which is an array-like object but not technically an array.

Comment: Oh yes. The API also says that. I was using getElementById('id').children for something else and that returned an array of children. I wonder why getElementByClass would return an array instead.

Comment: `children` is a property defined on [Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element). `getElementById` returns a single Element because ids are supposed to be unique. `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of Elements because multiple elements can share a classname.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because **getElementsByClassName** returns an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) or [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList). If you console log just that element, "notes" you will see why you are getting an undefined.

Replace your JS code by:

```
var navTabs = document.getElementsByClassName('notes');
console.log(navTabs);
```

That will output an array which once expanded, it will show the content of the position [0]. If you expand that one you will get your NodeList labeled as *childNodes*. Expand it and you will get your divs.

Try this to get directly your divs:

```
console.log('Items: ',navTabs[0].childNodes);
```